# Best way to do my main menu (ListView vs ScrollView + LinearLayout)

Tags: android, listview, scrollview, android-linearlayout

The main menu of my app should look like this : http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/31/accueilpart1.jpg/ and after a scroll http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/38/accueilpart2.jpg/

I'm kind of lost right now because I don't know what is the best way between a listview with clickable sections headers (I think I will have to use different adapter or one custom adapter with test like "if XXX.getClass() == Test.class") or the other option is a linear layout inside a scrollable view where I put each items myself (with an enum type maybe).

Can someone help me ?

Thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created that sort of look using a `ListView` and my [`MergeAdapter`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge).

In your case, it would appear to be an action bar (perhaps using ActionBarSherlock), for the bar with the logo, refresh button, etc., and a `ListView` holding:

- a `View` for each header (Actualité, etc.)
- a single `View` for the "main article" (Porrentruy)
- a series of `ListAdapters` for the articles inside of each header

Comment: I already have a view and an adapter for each item of the list (except for the main article and the headers). Do I have to change the adapter  for each different items (unising setAdapter) ? Something like this : I set the adapter for the main article, then I set the adapter for the header, then another adapter for the articles and so on ?

Comment: @Fr4nz: You add adapters to a `MergeAdapter` when you have several of the same thing in a row (e.g., videos). You add views to a `MergeAdapter` for individual things (e.g., headers, special "main" items).

Comment: Nice, looks great thank's for your answers, I'm going to try your MergeAdapter!

Comment: Your adapter is truly amazing, thank's again that's exactly what I was looking for :)